# Convert JSON to java script

Tags: javascript, json

Can anybody provide the java script for the below JSON. I tried in many way, but could not add the field **"set"**

```
{
   "student":[
      "set",
      [
         {
            "name":"abcd",
            "id":"1234"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: what is your question? what do you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "provide the java script for the below JSON"?

Comment: @ozil looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you sure it is JSON? (Is it a string?) Or is it JavaScript already? Read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: Can you please share one of the ways you tried?

Comment: It's valid JSON. But what does it mean to convert JSON to JavaScript? This sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you want to access your "set" value? `obj.student[0].set`?

Comment: If you want just to remove quotes - you can't do it for "set" because it's string value itself and not key in the object.

Comment: This is like one of those riddles where we have to find the question.

Comment: "set" is not a "field". Actually, we do not use that term in JavaScript at all. In your example, "set" is a string which the element of an array.

Answer (score 1):

So your `javaScript` variable would be an `object`having property/key name *student* of `array` type. Now student has two elements *set* a `string` and an `object`, other element is also an `array`, has an element of `object` type. This element has two properties/keys *name* and *id*.

```js
var required = {};
        required.student = [];
        required.student.push("set");
        var innerArray = [];
        var innerObj = {};
        innerObj.name = "abcd";
        innerObj.id = "1234";
        innerArray.push(innerObj);
        required.student.push(innerArray);

    document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(required,0, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(_the_object_given_);` does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but...

If you just want to have the JSON object you described available in your JavaScript code, you can just put it into a variable.

```js
var json = {
  "student":[
    "set",
    [
      {
        "name":"abcd",
        "id":"1234"
      }
    ]
  ]
};

// Testing the object:

// Print the JSON object we made, as a string
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

// Print the first item inside the 'student' array
console.log(json.student[0]);
```

If you instead have your JSON as a string, you can **parse it to JSON object** with:

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(jsonString);
Is a pure JavaScript approach so long as you can require a reasonably modern browser.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse